# After updating Fody from 2.0.0 (sample solution) to 2.3.1, assembly does not get built with debug information.

Tags: fody

Update from 2.0.0 to 2.3.1 in Fody, causes VS2015 to not build the assembly with debug information, meaning it's impossible to put a break point.  If I revert back to 2.0.0, it builds with debug info and break points come back.  The same Debug build configuration is used.  I also NuGet PropertyChanged.Fody but this problem occurs if I update Fody.  I used PropertyChanged.Fody 2.2.0 for both cases.

Comment: Fody.2.3.0 is okay, so it looks like it's a newly introduced problem in 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try updating to version 2.3.2 https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fody/2.3.2

and in the future it is better to raise issues here https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues